# Insufficient access to edit OpenLDAP cn=config with external SASL authentication

Tags: ubuntu, openldap

I want to add a schema to an OpenLDAP database that I've inherited.

```
ldapadd -vY EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f schema.ldif
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
...
adding new entry "cn=openssh-lpk,cn=schema,cn=config"
ldap_add: Insufficient access (50)
```

A discussion on the mailing list regarding the same [external SASL authentication issue](http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-technical/201201/msg00053.html) leads me to believe that I need to "map a SASL EXTERNAL identity to the `cn=config` rootdn." How would I accomplish this?

While trying to figure this out, I created a similar VM and installed slapd from the Ubuntu repos. External SASL requests like the one above work right out of the box. I attempted to compare the `cn=config` settings between the two systems but failed to identify any obvious clues to perform this task. The production database was originally running on Gentoo. I migrated it to Ubuntu and have been happily editing the accounts and using it.  However I've been unable to amend the configuration database since converting to the `cn=config` format during the migration.

Comment: Who is the rootDN on `cn=config`? `grep olcRootDN: /etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn\=config/olcDatabase\=\{0\}config.ldif`

Comment: There is no olcRootDN there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that there is one `olcAccess` attribute of the `{0}config` database (`/etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={0}config.ldif`) that looks like this:

```
olcAccess: {0}to * 
 by dn.exact=gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth manage 
 by * break
```

In the default config on Ubuntu, this is the only `olcAccess` entry for the config database. If you have more entries, make sure that the one I mentioned is the first (i. e. `{0}`) and the others follow (`{1}`, `{2}` etc.). Otherwise one of the others could match, assign too low permissions and stop traversing the list.

If there's some other user/DN in that list with sufficient (`write`, `manage`) permissions, you should preferably try to amend olcAccess with an `LDIF` file using `ldapmodify` with that user/DN.

Failing that, you can do:

```
sudo service slapd stop
sudo sensible-editor /etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn\=config/olcDatabase\=\{0\}config.ldif
sudo service slapd start
```

But you should fix the `CRC32` in that file afterwards.

Comment: you saved my day ... no one really no one mentioned someting like that on the arch linux wiki. One week for nothing!